# functions to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose a developer does not use prepared statements in mysql, so are the following three functions enough to prevent any SQL injection. I would be grateful if someone improves the following functions:

```
function SanitizeForSQL($str)
{
    if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
    {
        $ret_str = mysql_real_escape_string( $str );
    }
    else
    {
        $ret_str = addslashes( $str );
    }
    return $ret_str;
}

/*
Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
*/
function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
{
    $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

    if($remove_nl)
    {
        $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
            '/(\r+)/i',
            '/(\t+)/i',
            '/(%0A+)/i',
            '/(%0D+)/i',
            '/(%08+)/i',
            '/(%09+)/i'
        );
        $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
    }

    return $str;
}    
function StripSlashes($str)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

**Edit:
Due to the response from the experts, it seems above code is a crap. So I will be using prepared statements. I thank all of you it was an eye opener.**

Comment: `addslashes()` is to sql injection prevention as a piece of wet toilet paper is to cleaning up after a hurricane: it's utterly **USELESS**. your stripslashes function is USELESS and an outright syntax error - you cannot redeclare functions, especially built-in ones... unless this is all within an object that you haven't bothered showing.

Comment: How does `sanitize()` help in preventing SQL injection?

Comment: it's not clear how you would use these functions.

Comment: @MarcB: well, there's `$this`...

Comment: @MarcB mysql_real_escape_string is always used addslashes() is in the else statements.

Comment: doesn't matter. if you end up using addslashes, you might as well **NOT** use it. it's utterly useless and utterly dangerous. You'll think you're safe and end up getting injected anyways. The entirety of this code is beyond pointless and useless. The mysql_*() functions are deprecated, and you should be using mysqli or PDO anyways, both of which have FAR BETTER injection prevention capabilities. Any system which still has magic_quotes enabled should be tortured to death, shot in the head, cut up into tiny pieces, burned to ashes, and the ashes scattered to the winds

Comment: If prepared statements are unavailable, properly use the escaping function provided by the database API instead. There's always one. If there isn't, use another API.

Comment: @MarcB That's a pretty wishy-washy liberal stance you're taking there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to improve your code is to scrap it altogether.

Besides being wrong in that you'll introduce charset-related bugs if you ever store multibyte strings and that your escaping function *must* be charset-aware, both the `mysql` extension and `gpc` quotes and deprecated and heading the way of the dodo. Don't use either.

Use `pdo` instead, or `mysqli` if you're married with mysql. In either case use parametrized queries -- also known as prepared statements.

And for that matter, you can also use an ORM that is well established and thoroughly battle-tested. There are many. This ORM will take care of the SQL for you, so you can worry about actually writing your app instead of your own framework.